# Resgistrar listeners en clases javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy tratando de crear una clase javascript para un droparea, traté dos maneras distintas. La clase Droparea me permite acceder a las propiedades del objeto pero al presentarse el evento drop, no funciona e.preventDefault.
La clase Droparea2 permite evitar el comportamiento por defecto del evento drop, pero no me permite acceder a las propiedades del objeto, ¿Alguna solución?. Prefiero no utilizar ningun plugin.

```js
class Droparea {
 // Contructor
 constructor(div, property1){
  this.div = div;
  this.property1 = property1;
 }

 // Metodos 
 registerEvents(){
  this.in();
  this.out();
  this.drop();
  return;
 }

 in(){
  var div = this.div;
    var property1 = this.property1;
  div.addEventListener('dragover',function(){
   div.style.background = "yellow";
      div.innerHTML = property1 + '1';
  },false);
 }

 out(){
  var div = this.div;
    var property1 = this.property1;
  div.addEventListener('dragleave',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   div.style.background = "blue";
      div.innerHTML = property1 + '2';
  },false);
 }

 drop(){
  var div = this.div;
    var property1 = this.property1;
  div.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   div.style.background = "red";
      div.innerHTML = property1 + '3';
  },false);
 }
}

class Droparea2 {
 // Contructor
 constructor(div, property1){
  this.div = div;
  this.property1 = property1;
 }

 // Metodos 
 registerEvents(){
    this.div.addEventListener('dragover',this.in,false);
    this.div.addEventListener('dragleave',this.out,false);
    this.div.addEventListener('drop',this.drop,false);
 }

 in(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.style.background = 'yellow';
 }

 out(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.style.background = 'blue';
    e.target.innerHTML = this.property1;
 }

 drop(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.style.background = 'red';
 }
}
var div = document.querySelector('.droparea');
var drop = new Droparea(div,'Something');
var div2 = document.querySelector('.droparea2');
var drop2 = new Droparea2(div2,'Something');
drop.registerEvents();
drop2.registerEvents();
```

```css
.droparea {
  background: gray;
  height: 200px;
}

.droparea2 {
  background: darkgray;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="droparea">Arrastra tu elemento aqui. 1</div>
<div class="droparea2">Arrastra tu elemento aqui. 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si registra los listeners, el problema es que olvidaste prevenir la acción por defecto en el evento [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/dragover):

```
div.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // omitiste aquí
  div.style.background = "yellow";
  div.innerHTML = property1 + '1';
});
```

Recuerda que debes prevenir los eventos en los eventos [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/dragover), [`dragleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/dragleave) y [`drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/drop) si quieres personalizar comportamientos. Además, en caso desees usar un `dataTransfer` puedes simular uno con un objeto de instancia, ya que el objeto original `dataTransfer` solo está disponible en [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/dragstart) y [`drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/drop). Te dejo un ejemplo de ésto.

**Ejemplo DnD y File API**

```js
class AvatarUpload {
 constructor(id, data) {
   this.$el = document.getElementById(id);
    this.data = data;
    // simula el dataTransfer nativo
    this.dataTransfer = {};
    this.bindEvents();
  }
  
  bindEvents () {
   this.$el.addEventListener('dragover', this.over.bind(this));
    this.$el.addEventListener('dragleave', this.leave.bind(this));
    this.$el.addEventListener('drop', this.drop.bind(this));
  }
  
  over (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    this.dataTransfer.name = 'John Doe';
    this.$el.classList.add('over');
  }
  
  leave (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    this.$el.classList.remove('over');
  }
  
  drop (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    this.$el.classList.remove('over');
    this.toBase64(e).then(str => {
      this.$el.textContent = '';
     this.$el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${str})`;
      console.log('Propiedades propias:', this.data);
      console.log('DataTransfer:', this.dataTransfer);
      this.dataTransfer = {}; // reinicializa dataTransfer
    });
  }
  
  toBase64(e) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     let fileReader = new FileReader();
      let file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
      fileReader.onload = function () {
       resolve(this.result);
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }
}

new AvatarUpload('area', { property: 'Photo' });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');

#area {
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'josefin sans';
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

#area.over {
  border-color: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  Arrastra tu foto aquí
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Guz, podrias explicarme un poco la parte de `{ property: 'Photo' }`, no entiendo de donde saca la informacion que le envia al constructor.

Comment: Ese objeto no tiene mayor importancia. Lo puse como analogía a lo que haces tú al pasar un segundo parámetro. No tiene importancia.